# Appending two components in a single component in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, append, uipickerview

I had very minute problem since yesterday. I had 2 tables in the database one with Projects and other with Benefits. I want to add the two tables data in Single PickerView Component. For example Projects has pro1, proj2, proj3 and Benefits table has benefits1, benefits2. So I want to append both projects table dat and Benefits table data in a single PickerView component.

```
-(void)loadprojects
    {

        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@",[self.projectpicker dataSource]];

        // Code for Project loading
        NSString * BenefitString =@"http://test.com/GetBenefitTypes";

        NSURL *Benefiturl = [NSURL URLWithString:BenefitString];

        NSString *projecturltemp = @"http://test.com/GetAssignedProjects";
        NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserLoginIdSession"];
        NSString *usrid = str;
        NSString * projecturl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",projecturltemp,usrid];


        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:projecturl];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];




        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:Benefiturl];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/projectpicker" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/jsonArray" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];


        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                                timeoutInterval:30];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequestBenifits = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:Benefiturl
                                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                                timeoutInterval:30];


        // Make synchronous request
        urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                        returningResponse:&response
                                                    error:&error];
        urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequestBenifits
                                                   returningResponse:&response
                                                               error:&error];
        if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                                     options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

            NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                               options:0 error:&error];
            if(!entries)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
            }
            else{

                for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) {
                    projID = [entries valueForKey:@"ID_PROJECT"];
                    projectNames = [entries valueForKey:@"NM_PROJECT"];
                    BenefitsNames = [entries valueForKey:@"NM_LEAVES"];
                }
                //Combined = [BenefitsNames arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:projectNames];
                NSLog(@"Combined : %@", projectNames);
                //NSLog(@"projID : %@", projID);
                _projectpicker.delegate = self;
                _projectpicker.dataSource = self;
            }

        }       else {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you not use 2 components? What did you try so far? What didn't work?

Comment: I had three components in my pickerview, I want to add this befits and projects in 1 component

Comment: I was able to Load all the data in all the components, but I want this Benefits to be added to the projects component which is in component 1

Comment: So as 1 long list? Or you want to append the string names together for display?

Comment: can u show the result of Project names and Banefit names array

Answer (score 0):

Are projects and benefits `NSArray` instances? If so why not just combine them into one array and use that moving forward?

```
    NSArray *projects = @[@"pro 1", @"pro 2"];
    NSArray *benefits = @[@"benefit 1", @"benefit 2"];

    NSArray *combined = [projects arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:benefits];

    NSLog(@"Combined: %@", combined);
```

Combined prints out:

```
 Combined: (
     "pro 1",
     "pro 2",
     "benefit 1",
     "benefit 2" )
```

Then in your `- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component` method just return the `[combined objectAtIndex:row];`

Comment: I guess we were very close but I dont know where I was going wrong, let me edit the code for you

Answer (score 0):

[image]

base on my understanding, you wanna have something like above? am i correct? so multiple component in a UIPickerView?

if so, 1st thing, you need to set delegations to your ViewController ->

```
<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

then you implement the following methods in your ViewController.m file:
(I assume you have "NSArray *data" for projects and benefits ready...)

```
 //Number of rows to display in each component
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component==0) {
        return [self.listOfProjectsOfLeftCol count];
    }
    return [self.listOfBenefitsOfRightCol count];
}

//Number of columns to display
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

//define what to display in each rows and columns
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component==0) {
        return [self.listOfProjectsLeftCol objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    return [self.listOfBenefitsOfRightCol objectAtIndex:row];
}

//when the row is selected , do something...
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component==0) {

        //selected items in left column, now write your own code to do something...

    }

    else {
            //selected items in right column, now write your own code to do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: No Seph you had mistaken me, say suppose I had Benefits data in component 1 and projects data in component 2, I want this two benefits and projects data in one component

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what do you mean by the combine the two component into one.

But I guess you want combination of project and benefit as Project:Benefit

If so u can use following code snippet

```
    NSArray *arrProject=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Project1",@"Project2",nil];
    NSArray *arrBenefits=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Benefits1",@"Benefits2",nil];

    NSMutableArray *arrCombined=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<[arrProject count];i++)
    {
        [arrCombined addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",[arrProject objectAtIndex:i],[arrBenefits objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    NSLog(@"Combined:%@",arrCombined);
```

Its gives you result as

Combined:(
    "Project1:Benefits1",
    "Project2:Benefits2"
)

And then use the arrCombined for the date picker data source